# Cannot copy text from div when timer is refreshing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I have a chat with setInterval and it's refreshing a div (where messages are), but the problem is when i select the message with my mouse (blue marker) and for example i want to copy something from it, the timer refreshes the chat div and it won't let me do that. It automaticly disables the marked text, i hope you understand me what i'm talking about.

```
setInterval('test()', 1000);
function test(){
    $('#chatbox').load('load.php?chat_refresh');
    $("#online-users-text").load(location.href+ ' #online-users-text');
    <?php
    $query_chat = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    while($ch = $query_chat->fetch()){
        if($ch['status'] == 1){
            ?> Chat_Refresh(); <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
}
```

As you can see in the code, timer is calling `function test()` after every second, and that function is calling `$('#chatbox').load('load.php?chat_refresh');` which is refreshing `load.php?chatrefresh` from another page:

```
if(isset($_GET['chat_refresh'])){
    $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15) AS chat ORDER BY id ASC');
    while($r = $query->fetch()){
    $strText = preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a href="\0" target="_block">\0</a></span>', showBBcodes($r['message']) );
    ?>
    <?php if(empty($r['owner'])){ ?> <!-- Clear chat -->
        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
            <div class="header">
                <span style="line-height: 40px; visibility: hidden;">test</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <ul class="chat"> <!-- Show chat -->
            <li class="left clearfix">
            <span class="chat-img pull-left">
                <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL, $r['avatar']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" width='40' height='40' />
            </span>
                <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                    <div class="header">
                        <span style="line-height: 40px; color: #737373;">
                        <b><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>user.php?id=<?php echo escape($r['owner']); ?>"><?php echo $r['owner']; ?></a></b>:</span> <span class="text"><?php echo parseSmiley($strText); ?></span> <small style="line-height: 40px; margin-right: 5px;" class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo $r['created']; ?></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <?php }
    }
}
```

When i go to google chrome console, i can clearly see that timer is refreshing `#chatbox` div and that div is blinking.

Comment: That's because you are replacing all content within the `chat` div. If your chat posts have a unique ID you could request for only new chat content and append the new content to the chat `div` rather than loading all of the chat content every second? You could also count how many posts are within the chat container to remove older posts allowing you to only display x-amount of posts. Too many posts can eat up memory, more so if those posts contain images.

Comment: If you go with the method I have suggested then I would also recommend you replace `setInterval();` for `setTimeout();` and have that run after the ajax call has complete otherwise you might find double posts due to a second ajax call being made before the first one has completed.

Comment: @NewToJS Damn...looks hard

Comment: It's actually very easy and much better than reloading the same content over and over again. It does mean a little more work but when you want to be able to do more things (like selecting text within a chat) sometimes that little more work is what it will take to enable you to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @NewToJS I changed `setInterval(test, 1000)`; to `setTimeout(test, 1000);` but timer is not working now.

Comment: The recommendation to swap those is if you go with my suggestion in my first comment. I had to post as two due to a text limit on comments.

Comment: @NewToJS Sorry for your time, but it took me few months to make this where i am at and this what you said is too complicated to me because i don't understand good how to make it work that way. Thank you anyway...maybe one day i will make it correct.

Comment: Not a problem, it's all a part of learning. If it helps look into `ajax` `append` and `.remove()` to make thins easier you could make a test for each one, once understanding how to use them more you can put them together. I wish you the best with your application :)